# Dexing manually for Netbeans project

Tags: android, netbeans-7, dex

I have a NB7 Android project. Unfortunally Pre-dexing stops with heap out of memory. Is there a way to run Pre-dexing manually from command-line for Android SDK R21 to control memory assignment better ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about netbeans or how to control its predexing behavior, but it's a simple matter to run dx on a jar from the command line

```
 dx --dex --output=classes.dex blah.jar
```

Or, since you need to control the memory options

```
 dx -JXmx1G --dex --output=classes.dex blah.jar
```

You can find dx at `<android-sdk>/platform-tools/dx`

On the newer versions of sdk , you can find dx at

```
<android-sdk>/build-tools/android-<ver>/
```